# How to get the values from json service

Tags: ios, json

Hai I need to get the id & status from the service for login my code is below. please guide me to get the values.. Thanks in advance..

```
NSString *Username= txtUsername.text;
NSString *Password=txtPassword.text;
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxx/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@&format=json",Username,Password];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:link];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Bit of an older example, but the concepts still apply: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: -1 Make some effort to research your questions first.

Comment: Sorry i need to get the id and status from the service, so only i post this question please guide me to get the results i am very new to xcode please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1st Do the jSon parsing and then get the particular value from the
  key .
- Before getting any value , we have to understand the tree of jSon.
- Here "posts" is an NSArray ,within that one DIctionary "post" is
  there ,which again contains another dictionary.
- Below is the complete code.

> - (void)viewDidLoad 
>     {
>
>   [super viewDidLoad];
>
>   NSString *Username= txtUsername.text;
>
>   NSString *Password=txtPassword.text;
>
>   NSString *link = 
>     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.some.com/webservice/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@&format=json",Username,Password];
>
>   dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
>
>   ```
>   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
>     kLatestKivaLoansURL];
>
>   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
>     withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
>   ```
>
>   }); }

Then call that selector fetchedData

> - (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
>
>   //parse out the json data
>
>   NSError* error;
>
>   NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
>     options:kNilOptions 
>         error:&error];
>
>   if(!error){
>
>   NSArray* postArray = [json objectForKey:@“posts”]; //This is an array
>
>   if (postArray.count>0) {
>
>   ```
>   NSDictionary *dict = [[postArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"post" ];
>
>   NSString *id_ = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
>   NSString *status_ = [dict objectForKey:@"status"];
>   ```
>
>   }
>     }
>     }

Comment: Whats wrong with this ???? Why Down vote???

Comment: sorry for late replay sat & sunday is a holyday now only i have seen your answer and i got two errors in it thats is, 1.Use of undeclared identifier kBgQueue. 2.Unexpected @ in pgm before"posts" please guide me thank you..

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that #define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(
 DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
You can get the full post from Reywenderlich    http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: ok thank you I got the answer and now am lacking in the if condition. My condition is if(id1!=NULL&&status!=0) bt it allows even the condition fails please help me...

Comment: id and status are the strings .so to check if that is NULL or not .Write the condition as  if(id1.length >0 && status.length >0)

Comment: thank you but i need the status as integer value to validate. so how can i convert the status to int please guide me & Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Convet NSString to  NSInteger  and then Check ... NSInteger statusInt =[status integerValue]. if (id1.length >0 && statusInt != 0)

Comment: Thank you but it shows error [__NSArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7518410

Comment: Can you print you jSon Dictionary ?? What are you getting ?Is it a NSString or NSArray?

Comment: S i got the json values but i can't convert it My code is NSString *status=[resMap valueForKey:@"status"]; NSInteger statusInt =[status integerValue]; NSLog(@"%d", statusInt);

Comment: @Ragul...Just print the output dictionary which you are getting ...It will solve the problem .. It might not be a NSString .What is the type of data you are getting for "status" key ?Is it a NSArray ????

Comment: S i got the values from array and convert it to NSString if its a valid user i got 1 else its 0

Comment: NSArray *resultsMap = [res valueForKey:@"posts"];
    NSArray *resMap = [resultsMap valueForKey:@"post"];
    NSString *id1=[resMap valueForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *status=[resMap valueForKey:@"status"];

Comment: See You can't convert NSArray to NSString. NSString *status_ = [dict objectForKey:@"status"]ObjectAtIndex:0]; get the value whatever  you want at which index like 0 or 1 or etc and that will be a NSString and then Convert NSString to NSInteger and then check your condition   ....

Comment: objectForKey shows error i gave valueForKey now it shows no known method for selector ObjectAtIndex

Comment: @Ragul.Just print the log of your output ..otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: I print it i got the correct results but only to check the condition i want to convert it to int that is the prob

Comment: This is the id & status i have printed    2014-06-16 15:34:13.789 Tranzlogix[2232:11303] (
    20
)
2014-06-16 15:34:13.789 Tranzlogix[2232:11303] (
    1
)

Comment: Print the dictionary value  here . where ar eu printing ???

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you so much now i got the results

Comment: Good morning could you Please help me "How to pass the id value into another page?" Thank you..

Comment: Hai i am blocked for asking questions i have a doubt could you please help me?

Comment: i am trying to add image in MKMap but it shows error kindly guide me the error is "Property 'image' not found on object of type 'Annotation *'" and my code is "myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"]" i am blocked for ask questions please help me Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your json string.  You can use NSJSONSERIALISATION to convert data (json string ) into NSDictionary. Then use the keys to extract the values. I'm replying through mobile so I can't write the actual code.

Comment: i am trying to add image in MKMap but it shows error kindly guide me the error is "Property 'image' not found on object of type 'Annotation *'" and my code is "myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"]" i am blocked for ask questions please help me Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Use Below code to parse Json in IOS

```
NSString *Username= txtUsername.text;
NSString *Password=txtPassword.text;

NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.some.com/_webservice/login.php?user=%@&pass=%@&format=json",Username,Password];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:link];


NSMutableURLRequest *req1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response;

NSError *error;

//getting the data
NSData *newData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req1 returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSLog(@"basavaraj  \n\n\n %@ \n\n\n",responseString);




NSData* data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *myError = nil;

NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];




NSString  *id=[res objectForKey:@"ID"];

NSString  *status=[res objectForKey:@"Status"];
```

and if u need extra info please go through below link it may help you

[Click here for more details](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/)

Comment: Sorry for late replay i used your code but i only get null values in id & status pls guide me thank you

Comment: i am trying to add image in MKMap but it shows error kindly guide me the error is "Property 'image' not found on object of type 'Annotation *'" and my code is "myAnnotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pizza_slice_32.png"]" i am blocked for ask questions please help me Thank you